# Vue v-for after condition using vuex

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

While I am trying to create a form I encountered this problem which I don't have any solution. 
There is a Vuex data on Vehicles Make and Model of vehicle, now once the make is selected, I want the other form to loop through the selected Make and find other models... something like that.

Here is what I did so far:

cars.js - (vuex module)

```
const state = {
  make: [
   {
    name: 'Audi',
    carid: '1',
    models: [
     {
     modelid: '1.1',
     name: 'A7',
     },
     {
     modelid: '1.2',
     name: 'A8',
     },
    ],
   },
   {
   name: 'BMW',
   carid: '2',
   models: [
    {
    modelid: '2.1',
    name: '5 Series',
    },
    {
    modelid: '2.2',
    name: '7 Series',
    },
   ],
   },
 ],
}
```

Cars.vue

```
<template>
<div class="labelos">
              <div class="label-name">
                <h4>Car make:</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="label-body">
                <label for="car-make">
                  <select v-model="selectedType" name="carmake" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option  v-for="(cars, index) in cars.make" :key="index" :value="cars.carid">{{ cars.name }}</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="labelos">
              <div class="label-name">
                <h4>Car model:</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="label-body">
                <label for="car-model">
                  <select>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option v-for="(model, index) in cars.make" :key="index" :value="cars.carid">{{ model.carid }}</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
                Model:
              </div>
            </div>
    </template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name: 'cars',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedType: '',
      selectedCity: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {

  },
  components: {
    Headers,
    Footers,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'cities', 'cars',
    ]),
  },
};
</script>
```

So as you can see on first label I am looping through makes, and once a car make is selected that carid is saved on selectedType, now how is that possible to load second dropdown according to that selection, so if carid 1 is selected, the list will load car models available on given carid (in this example carid 1)

Looking forward to hear from someone, I am stuck here.. I don't know any solution how to do this... this is so far I have done

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a computed property which returns model options based on the value of the selected make type. Then you can bind to that and it will automatically update whenever the selected make changes:

```
models() {
  if (this.selectedType) {
    return this.cars.make.find((car) => car.carid === this.selectedType).models;
  }
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cars: {
      make: [{
        name: 'Audi',
        carid: '1',
        models: [
          { modelid: '1.1', name: 'A7' },
          { modelid: '1.2', name: 'A8' },
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'BMW',
        carid: '2',
        models: [
          { modelid: '2.1', name: '5 Series' },
          { modelid: '2.2', name: '7 Series' }
        ],
      }]
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      selectedType: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState(['cars']),
    models() {
      if (this.selectedType) {
        return this.cars.make.find((car) => car.carid === this.selectedType).models;
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h4>Car make:</h4>
  <select v-model="selectedType" name="carmake" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option  v-for="(cars, index) in cars.make" :key="index" :value="cars.carid">{{ cars.name }}</option>
  </select>

  <h4>Car model:</h4>
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option v-for="(model, index) in models" :key="index" :value="model.modelid">{{ model.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time, I got stuck on this and you saved my life. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Working example with your data:

```js
const state = {
  make: [
    {
      name: 'Audi',
      carid: '1',
      models: [
       {modelid: '1.1', name: 'A7'},
       {modelid: '1.2', name: 'A8'}
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'BMW',
      carid: '2',
      models: [
        {modelid: '2.1',  name: '5 Series'},
        {modelid: '2.2',  name: '7 Series'}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    state: state,
    selected: 0
  },
  computed: {
    models () {
      var maker = this.state.make.find(m => m.carid === this.selected)
      return maker ? maker.models : []
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option value="0" selected>Choose maker</option>
    <option
      v-for="maker in state.make"
      :key="maker.carid"
      :value="maker.carid"
    >{{ maker.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select>
    <option value="0" selected>Select model</option>
    <option
      v-for="model in models"
      :key="model.modelid"
      :value="model.modelid"
    >{{ model.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

If you can, change 'modelid' to simple integers - 1, 2, etc., at least. And if you can and you know how to do it, change your data structure - divide makers and models to separate arrays/objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin for this specific task you're trying to accomplish: [vue-dependon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dependon).

It hasn't been updated for 1-2years, but I think that you can check its source code and see how it works.

*UPDATE*:
All you need from the [sourcecode](https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-dependon/blob/master/vue-dependon.js) is the `loadOptions` function and the code between L83 and L105.
You can adapt that code to your needs.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I Can not use that code.. It's not been updated and I believe there is another way to do this and not use any other plugin. But thnx for your time ;)

Comment: You can look through its sourcecode, it's only 126 lines of code, from which almost a half are comments.

Comment: I didn't downvote you mate.. when I cam here first I saw it was downvoted, and now It's not..